# Pass arguments to hook_form_alter()

Tags: forms, users

I have two login boxes on the same page and, I would like to integrate different behaviors to those based on some arguments.

I'm calling myself the forms with `drupal_get_form('user_login');`. I would like to pass a variable to the form:

```
drupal_get_form('user_login', $myvar);
```

And then be able to get it from a `hook_form_alter()`:

```
function mymodule_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id, $myvar) {
  // some code here
}
```

But i can't find a way to do this.

Comment: hook_form() is something completely else, I assume you mean hook_form_alter().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The passed arguments are kept in `$form_state['build_info']['args']`. You can find a documentation of the $form_state structure here: [drupal_build_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7).

Comment: My question was for D6, anyway thanks a lot, the answer you gave helped me finding the right solution for D6:

The arguments are in $form['#parameters'][argument];

Comment: Search about one day to find this one here. Works great. Just giving the register form a string and reading it out via the build_info. Cool.